# How to print two different loops next to each other

Tags: java, loops, printing

I have a file that has a list of names along with their sex and a count of how many people have the name. I want to print the top 10 female and male names side by side . My issue is when i run my program this is what it prints.

**What is Printing**

```
"Female"    "Male"

Isabella
            Jacob
Sophia
            Ethan
Emma
            Michael
Addison
Elizabeth
Ella           
            William
Olivia
            Alexander

Ava 
            Joshua
            Mason
Emily
Abigail
            Evan
            Nicholas
            Gavin
```

I want them to be lines up together like this

```
"Female"    "Male"

Isabella     Jacob
Sophia       Ethan
Emma         Michael
Addison      William
Elizabeth    Alexander    
Ella         Joshua
Olivia       Mason
Ava          Evan
Emily        Nicholas
Abigail      Gavin
```

---

```
for (String s : descending())
 {
    for (int i = 0 ;i < 168;i++)
    {
    if('F' == oneName.get(i).getSex())
    {

    System.out.println(oneName.get(i).getName());

    }
    if('M' == oneName.get(i).getSex())
    {

    System.out.printf("%20.10s%n",oneName.get(i).getName());

    }
    }
        break;
}
```

Comment: why two loop? one loop is enough to do this. put single SOP and print both the values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a line feed here:

```
System.out.println(oneName.get(i).getName());
```

so change it to:

```
System.out.print(oneName.get(i).getName());
```

**EDIT:** And you need a line feed after male names. So do this:

```
System.out.printf("%20.10s%n",oneName.get(i).getName());
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: Well, you do, not just on that line ;)

Comment: that just puts the girls names on the same line and messes it all up

Comment: That still prints all the female names on one line.

Comment: Adding \n to the prinf is a better option than a call to println for a line feed - %20.10s%n **\n**